# laravel add error message to specific dynamic field

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a form with dynamic fields (multiple users added dynamicly with one form)

I'm trying to add an error message to a specific field after a manual validation (with a basic if)

I've tried the following and none of this work

```
$validator->errors()->add('password.0', 'Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas');

$validator->errors()->add('password.*', 'Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas');

$validator->errors()->add('password[0]', 'Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas');
```

I can't make the message bag accepting my message and at the end, "$validator->errors()" doesn't contain the message for my field password[0]

Does anybody knows how to make it work?

Comment: please show us your dynamic form

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password[0]" autofocus="" tabindex="5">

I can retrieve the value, but the issue is just with the error message bag, i can't put an error to a specific field like i showed.

EDIT: I'm doing it in ajax, so the problem is that "$validator->errors()" doesn't contain my newly added error with the command indicated above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

base on the inputs you have which they are arrays I think validating using laravel rules for array would be good.
here is the documentation for [array validations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#validating-arrays).

something like :

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'password.*' => 'required', // your rules
] , [
'password.*.required' => "your message"
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @Masoud is good, i could make it work with that specific code

```
'password.*' => ['required',
   function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
        $arr_explode_attr = explode(".",$attribute);
        if ($value != request()->input('password_confirmation.'.$arr_explode_attr[1])) {
                        return $fail('Les mots de passe ne correspondent pas');
    }
}];
```

Thanks for your help =)